# Is there a way to display images from the internet immediately with zero delay?

Tags: flutter

My idea is to **predownload** them upon the first page or the page in question before the widgets are displayed, and then once they are downloaded, **displaying the images will be as fast as displaying a Text widget for instance**.

I have researched a lot based on Cached Network Images, Flutter Cache Manager and precache images, but *all of them have a delay in loading the image*.

The idea is that since it is finished downloading, it should display it immediately. And the downloading should happen in secret, before the page is loaded.

Any solutions?

Comment: what *exactly* did you try? what about [precacheImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html)?

Comment: Yes I've tried it, it isn't immediate, there is a fade in for it.

Comment: *"it isn't immediate"* - so you would like to call `precacheImage` with a big network image (for example 2MB) to be shown immediately?

Comment: @pskink Correct, that's what I want to achieve. Any image that should be precached or downloaded, and the displaying of it should have zero delay, it should pop up immediately.

Comment: this is exactly what `precacheImage` is doing but do not expect 2MB image to be downloaded and decoded in 0 seconds - thats why `precacheImage` returns a `Future` that completes when image is downloaded and decoded - the docs say: *"Prefetches an image into the image cache.

Returns a Future that will complete when the first image yielded by the ImageProvider is available or failed to load."*

Comment: @pskink Maybe I'm doing the widget wrong then. How do I fetch the precached image and use it as an Image widget for a child say in a `SizedBox`?

Comment: you have to use `Imsge` widget after the `Future` returned by `precacheImage` completes - you can use `StatefulWidget` or `FutureBuilder` or similar stuff for rebuilding

Comment: Right, one more thing then, how do I store the cached images in the phone storage, so that when the app is opened next time, it loads from the cache instead of fetching from the URL again?

Comment: @Jiehfeng were you able to find any solution for this, we have the same issue right now. We created an app as a kiosk of products. Caching is working fine and in offline mode. However, there's a bit of a delay in displaying cached images which is not ideal for a kiosk app.

Comment: @JeromeMiranda Sadly there's no way that I can see. A workaround I can suggest is using `progressIndicatorBuilder` and have a `List<boolean>` to monitor if an image is already loaded in or not, and then in your code, display the products page only when all the booleans are true; if not, display a loading indicator. That way it will appear to be immediate, but with your previous loading screen taking a bit longer.

Comment: @JeromeMiranda The other solution is what pskink recommended, in your `initstate` simply use `prechacheImage`, this will ensure the build method does not get called until all images are already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

cached_network_image support precache

https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/646#issuecomment-905275798

and also

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html

Comment: Please see this link for the result, it isn't immediate still: https://i.imgur.com/chzdTvN.mp4
The first image is precache, the second is a standard Image.network(). The second is somehow better looking, precache seems to have some sort of animation or it just isn't immediate.